# Write __TIMESTAMP__ to separate file in Visual Studio on build

Tags: visual-studio-2015, unix-timestamp

I'm using the `__TIMESTAMP__` in my code to get the build date on runtime. Internally I'm converting it to the unix time to use it as the build number. I would like to have the unix time of the build date in a file next to my binary. Is it possible to write it there on compilation with VS2015?